# Cannot start WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager in CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, csom, workflow-manager

I have been trying to manage workflows using Powershell, namely to be able to perform bulk termination of workflows.
However, I am unable to initialise the WorkflowServicesManager in CSOM.
I had the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll` in version 16, and the Sharepoint is on-premises 2016.

Here is the code

```
# path to installed modules
$path = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\3.12.1908.1"

# reference to needed assemblies
Add-Type -Path "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"

$siteUrl = "https://mysite/sites/"

Connect-PnPOnline $siteUrl -useWeblogin
$clientContext = Get-PnPContext

$rootWeb= $clientContext.Web
$clientContext.Load($rootWeb)
$clientContext.Load($rootweb.Lists)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$webWFAssociations=$rootWeb.WorkflowAssociations
$clientContext.Load($webWFAssociations)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$WorkflowServicesManager = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($clientContext,$rootWeb)
$WorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService()
```

Here is the error

```
New-object : Cannot find an overload for "WorkflowServicesManager" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\Users\My User\Documents\Sharepoint\Workflows.ps1:26 char:28
+ ... esManager = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.W ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to multiple WorkflowServicesManager assemblies being registered.

Run this command in ps-

```
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | ?{$_.CodeBase -match "WorkflowServices"}
```

If you have more than one WorkflowServicesManager assembly, you need to take some steps. I actually had two. One was significantly older than the other. So I just copied the new one and replaced the old one with the copy so there would be no conflict.